# A variable returns nothing at foreach loop in php, but if i return before, it has value

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I have a problem with some script in php. I'm trying to find out what's happening, so i've found the place where the mistake appears.

```
 function doSomething($var){

  $sql= "SELECT * FROM products";
  $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
  $spts=array();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $res->num_rows - 1; $i++) {
            $res->data_seek($i);
            $spts[$i] = $res->fetch_assoc();
        }

  **return $var;**
  foreach($spts as $spt){
    **return $var;**
  }
```

As you can see in the code below, i've added two return statements. The mistake here is that when i return $var before the foreach statement, it returns the value that i've passed the function, but then, in the foreach, it doesn't return anything, even if i put it at first line.

I've been looking for in another questions but nobody talks about this specific error. I don't know if i'm doing something wrong. Why $var loses its value?

Comment: Is it not returning, or returning a NULL value?

Comment: Inside the `foreach` loop write `print_r($var)die;` and see if $var prints something or not.

Comment: Why you do return in foreach? It means that loop will perform only once and it will return 1st `$spt`

Comment: `var_dump()` is your friend.

Comment: I'm returning in foreach because i'm debugging for trying to see the value of a variable inside another method that it's called in that foreach, the code is a summary imitation

Comment: My guess is that your summary is wrong. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/168341) and post the real code. Also, after the first for loop, `var_dump($spts)` and make sure it's not empty.

Comment: It is not returning, what i do is show the message returned in a popup. When i return before foreach, the message appears in the popup, but if i do in foreach, the popup is empty.

Comment: The summary it's not wrong, only i've changed the name of variables and methods, and deleted the code after the return in the foreach because it is unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your `$spts` is empty, therefore no foreach loop is executed, therefore nothing is returned from a return **inside** the foreach loop. (PHP skips the loop, and the function comes to the natural EOF-Return.)

try it with `return count($spts)` to see, if you have a result, and at least one iteration of the foreach. (but return that **before** entering the foreach, or you are facing the same problem again.)

Also you could add a "no result" return after the foreach:

```
foreach($spts as $spt){
    return $var;
}
return "no result";
```